# Run Kong in Docker, Kong does not show GUI in web browser

Tags: docker, microservices, api-gateway, kong

I follow tutorial https://docs.konghq.com/install/docker/?_ga=2.46631079.1600317329.1601919139-2083746525.1601653016

Run Kong API Gateway in Docker

```
docker network create kong-net

docker run -d --name kong-database --network=kong-net -p 5432:5432 -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" -e "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong" postgres:9.6

docker run --rm --network=kong-net -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" kong:latest kong migrations bootstrap

docker run -d --name kong --network=kong-net -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" -p 8000:8000 -p 8443:8443 -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 -p 127.0.0.1:8444:8444 kong:latest
```

error

```
migrating hmac-auth on database 'kong'...
hmac-auth migrated up to: 000_base_hmac_auth (executed)
hmac-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)
hmac-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating oauth2 on database 'kong'...
oauth2 migrated up to: 000_base_oauth2 (executed)
oauth2 migrated up to: 003_130_to_140 (executed)
oauth2 migrated up to: 004_200_to_210 (executed)
oauth2 migrated up to: 005_210_to_211 (executed)
migrating ip-restriction on database 'kong'...
ip-restriction migrated up to: 001_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating jwt on database 'kong'...
jwt migrated up to: 000_base_jwt (executed)
jwt migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)
jwt migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating basic-auth on database 'kong'...
basic-auth migrated up to: 000_base_basic_auth (executed)
basic-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)
basic-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating key-auth on database 'kong'...
key-auth migrated up to: 000_base_key_auth (executed)
key-auth migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)
key-auth migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating session on database 'kong'...
session migrated up to: 000_base_session (executed)
migrating acl on database 'kong'...
acl migrated up to: 000_base_acl (executed)
acl migrated up to: 002_130_to_140 (executed)
acl migrated up to: 003_200_to_210 (executed)
acl migrated up to: 004_212_to_213 (executed)
migrating response-ratelimiting on database 'kong'...
response-ratelimiting migrated up to: 000_base_response_rate_limiting (executed)
migrating bot-detection on database 'kong'...
bot-detection migrated up to: 001_200_to_210 (executed)
migrating acme on database 'kong'...
acme migrated up to: 000_base_acme (executed)
38 migrations processed
38 executed
Database is up-to-date

C:\Users\donhuvy>docker run -d --name kong --network=kong-net -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" -e "KONG_PG_USER=kong" -e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong" -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" -p 8000:8000 -p 8443:8443 -p 127.0.0.1:8001:8001 -p 127.0.0.1:8444:8444 kong:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/kong" is already in use by container "1326822f2bfefe7b5f5ab76ef630c83127eb7e5661929009c6c0187c0be711ed". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\donhuvy>
```

[image]

From web browser, go to: [http://localhost:8001](http://localhost:8001/)

I also turn off Tomcat docker

[image]

[image]
I don't see GUI web, How to fix it?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kong GUI (Manager) is part of the kong enterprise edition.
If you are using kong community edition,
Have a look at https://pantsel.github.io/konga/ and there are few others developed by community for long UI

Comment: konga seems unmainteined, and it seems there's no other project active. It's true that the manager is for the enterprise edition, the documentation is a bit confusing... at least for me, I thougt it's free for all!, like for OSS edition too. I triple check the section "Enable Kong Manager" but I couldn't get it working...
It takes me a lot until i realize to hoover the mouse on the FREE word in the section. I want to kill myself and every kind of life for the time wasted!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean like Kong manager GUI?
it http://localhost:8002
port 8001 is an admin port it use to configurated your kong .